# i am trying to show pie chart for my requirement

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

```
<apex:page controller="RepresingusingAggrgate" title="Pie Chart">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="using aggregate results">
            <apex:chart data="{!CasesByStatus}" height="400" width="3980">
                <apex:pieSeries labelField="id" dataField="cnt">
                    <apex:chartLabel display="rotate" field="cnt" />
                </apex:pieSeries>
            </apex:chart>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class RepresingusingAggrgate {
    List < AggregateResult > CasesByStatus {get;set;}
    public RepresingusingAggrgate() {}
    public List < AggregateResult > getCasesByStatus() {
        AggregateResult[] result = [Select Account.Name name, Count(Id) ids From Contact Group By Account.Name, AccountId limit 100];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hi, I am trying to show pie chart but `<apex:chart>` is not working properly. Only the chart not displayed.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I guess you want to say something more :)

Comment: I just tried to show a pie chart,but <apex:char is not properly working

Comment: are you seeing any error on console?? Press f12 on browser.

Comment: not showing any console errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names here:

```
<apex:pieSeries labelField="id" dataField="cnt">
    <apex:chartLabel display="rotate" field="cnt" />
</apex:pieSeries>
```

must match the names used in the data (`name` and `ids` in your case) so:

```
<apex:pieSeries labelField="name" dataField="ids">
    <apex:chartLabel display="rotate" field="ids" />
</apex:pieSeries>
```

is more likely to work.

**PS**

Looks like the name references have to be properties meaning you need to return instances of a wrapper class rather than the `AggregateResult` objects:

```
public with sharing class RepresingusingAggrgate {
    public class Item {
        public String label {get; set;}
        public Integer data {get; set;}
        public Item(String label, Integer data) {
            this.label = label;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        Item[] items = new Item[] {};
        for (AggregateResult ar : [
                Select Account.Name name, Count(Id) ids
                From Contact
                Where Account.Name != null
                Group By Account.Name, AccountId
                limit 100
                ]) {
            items.add(new Item((String) ar.get('name'), (Integer) ar.get('ids')));
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

The chart also fails to render if the name value is null so the null check in the query is important too.

The Visualforce that works with the above controller is:

```
<apex:page controller="RepresingusingAggrgate" title="Pie Chart">
    <apex:chart data="{!items}" height="400" width="380">
        <apex:pieSeries labelField="label" dataField="data">
            <apex:chartLabel display="rotate" field="data"/>
        </apex:pieSeries>
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: hi Keith C,if i match the names used in data also,not working.

Comment: @sahi My bad. See the PS.

Comment: hi Keith C,it works for me now,in the pie chart it is showing only 100,vat if,i have more than 100 records,to resolve this i want to show others in the pie chart,,how can i create,,thanks in advance.

Comment: i want to add if to show 10 records in else i want to others,how can i a chieve

Comment: @sahi You could break the data out into multiple charts.

Comment: Hi keith C,i had added 2 more queries like bellow,List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
                 Integer con = [select count() from contact where AccountId in :acc];,i want to pass this count in something like this,,items.add(new Item(String),(Integer)con.get(t);,,how can i do it,please help me to create one more section in pie chat with that count

Comment: @sahi If you want an extra section, add an extra `Item` instance to the list in `getItems`.